# Getting IP address from another subnet's DHCP

Tags: networking, dhcp, subnet, dhcp-server

As in the diagram below I have two routers on two different subnets.
I connected them together but have not set static routes yet.

[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPipe.png)

However, when connecting from Access Point A's SSID, I get an IP from Router B on its network (192.168.2.x), and when connecting via Access Point B, I get an IP from Router A (192.168.0.x).
Also, the DHCP relay function is disabled on Router A (EdgeRouter X), but didn't find that option on Router B (TP-Link R470T+).

How to make sure only the DHCP server on the same network responds to DHCP requests?
I am trying to block UDP ports 67/68 on the outgoing interface of the Edgerouter without any success so far, but I hoped there might be a more straightforward solution.

Thank you.

Comment: so AP A **always**  gives a router B address and AP B **always** gives a router A address? perhaps your network is *actually* wired with AP A connected to Router B and AP B connected to Router A? That would definitely produce the result you're apparently observing - try swapping AP's around

Comment: @JaromandaX The AP are definitely connected to the right routers (the individual networks have always been separate before and the AP's SSID are distinct to each network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was due to misconfiguring the IP address of the Edgerouter interfaces, now all is working as it should, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without a relay, it's *not possible* for a DHCP server to respond to DHCP discoveries/requests from another subnet / layer 2 segment.

DHCP discovery or request are sent to the (limited) broadcast address, and broadcasts are not forwarded by a router.

The situation you describe is only possible when there is a relay (consumer routers don't relay) or when your diagram is incorrect.